# Asynchronous calls from VF page to controller method

Tags: visualforce, asynchronous, cpulimit

On a visualforce page that I created to upload documents, I tried to upload 500 documents at once. But it always exceeds the CPU time limit. Is there a way to invoke controller method Asynchronously for 500 times? Or any suggestion on how to bypass the CPU time limit? Thank you.

Comment: Any specific reason not to use DataLoader?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Javascript Remoting to split up your calls to the server. Javascript Remoting has a callback function which you could use for subsequent calls to the server:

More details on JS Remoting here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm

Here's an example of what it would look like with the callback handler (taken from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRemoteAccount() {
    var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',
        accountName, 
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this
                document.getElementById('remoteAcctId').innerHTML = result.Id
                document.getElementById(
                    "{!$Component.block.blockSection.secondItem.acctNumEmployees}"
                    ).innerHTML = result.NumberOfEmployees;
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                    event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
}
</script>
```